# How to send inline keyboard for Telegram bot from Inline editor Dialogflow ES(Fulfillment section)?

Tags: node.js, npm, dialogflow-es, telegram-bot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Sometimes I use Dialogflow ES Fulfillment to build Telegram bots. To finish functionality, I need to send the inline_keyboard filled with API data from the Inline editor section. To simplify the problem, I want to send just a static inline_keyboard, but there is a structure error or something wrong recognition property of "chat" or "payload".

Searched all posts, videos and documentation, gpt also does not help. Please someone save me :)
Thanks in advance!

Here is my index.js (need to replace the token) and package.json files. I tried to catch errors, but it does not work from the beginning.

As I know (not sure), it is not possible to use libraries such as:

- node telegram bot api
- messaging-api-telegram
- Telegraf

I tried to use them, but there is an issue with applying tokens from standard integration and the fulfillment section simultaneously.

**Index.js:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function sendInlineKeyboard(agent) {
    const detectIntentRequestPayload = agent.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload;
    if (!detectIntentRequestPayload || !detectIntentRequestPayload.data || !detectIntentRequestPayload.data.chat || !detectIntentRequestPayload.data.chat.id) {
      console.error('Unable to get chat ID from payload data.');
      return;
    }

    const chatId = detectIntentRequestPayload.data.chat.id;

    const keyboard = {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [{ text: 'button 1' }],
        [{ text: 'button 2' }],
      ],
    };

    const telegramBotToken = 'YOUR telegram bot token'; // Replace with your Telegram Bot token

    const payload = {
      chat_id: chatId,
      text: 'Choose an option:',
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboard),
    };

    axios.post(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${telegramBotToken}/sendMessage`, payload)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Inline keyboard sent successfully');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending inline keyboard:', error);
      });
  }

  function testIntentHandler(agent) {
    agent.add('Hello from testIntentHandler');
    sendInlineKeyboard(agent);
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('test', testIntentHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agent using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.24.1",
    "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.4"
  }
}
```

**Error:** (deleted personal data)

```
{
  "textPayload": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined\n    at sendInlineKeyboard (/workspace/index.js:9:63)\n    at testIntentHandler (/workspace/index.js:39:5)\n    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:313:44)\n    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/workspace/index.js:44:9)\n    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:50:16)\n    at process.nextTick (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:98:17)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)",
  "insertId": "",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
      "project_id": ""
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-06-27T16:01:38.949769Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "instance_id": "",
    "execution_id": ""
  },
  "logName": "projects//logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects//traces/c5cb2aa96a5d51fed5e6ef2e154db5a9",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-06-27T16:01:39.238846151Z"
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but I see you're using Axios. Axios was a necessary tool in the past but a better API is now available natively in all browsers and Node (and Web workers!). Consider using the modern [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of Axios.

Comment: I find a solution myself. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: @James Do you mean this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch ?

Comment: No, I meant the native `fetch` API. You don't need to install an external library; it is built in to recen versions of Node. [Here's a blog post going into more detail](https://blog.logrocket.com/fetch-api-node-js/).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use:

```js
const chatId = detectIntentRequestPayload.data.chat.id;
```

Instead use:

```
const chatId = agent.originalRequest.payload.data.chat.id;
```